# List Property Using Auto-Implemented Getter/Setter Returns 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: c#

Why does the C# code below allow auto-implemented properties for a List type that then results in an object reference runtime error? I realize that I can implement the getter and initialize the List but would like to know if there is a reason behind the behavior.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.FooList.Add(3);
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public List<int> FooList { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: How would the auto property know how to create an instance of the type?

Comment: So to clarify, it seems to me that taking care of: FooList = new List<int>(); would make sense. Is there another decision I would make with this property other than that which would make this not advisable?

Comment: If you would initialize all auto-implemented properties by calling their default constructor that could cause side effects. Also, how do you want to assign `null` then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - What side effects? That is the essence of my question. Re null, wouldn't it be preferable to allow null assignment to be the case when you have to explicitly create getter?

Comment: @markm247: a constructor can be arbitrarily expensive. Basically it can do anything.

Answer (score 6):

It is a property, It hasn't been instantiated yet. You can instantiate it in the constructor of the class or in your `Main` method.

```
class Foo
{
    public List<int> FooList { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        FooList = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Or in your `Main` method like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.FooList = new List<int>();
    foo.FooList.Add(3);
}
```

**Or with C# 6.0 you can do:**

```
class Foo
{
    public List<int> FooList { get; set; } = new List<int>();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Habib. Your comment on the C# 6.0 method is very much the shorthand I was looking for and is great to know.

Answer (score 4):

You need to initialise the list in the constructor of the `Foo` object

```
class Foo
{
    public List<int> FooList { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        FooList  = new List<int>();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that David. That is preferable to implementing the getter to me, but I still wonder if there is a reason C# doesn't do this for me.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question "What is the reason behind the behavior?"