# Automatic Implemented Property leads to a Null Reference while full written Property does not

Tags: vb.net, properties, nullreferenceexception

Could anyone tell me why executing this

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim currentSourceData As New SourceData
        currentSourceData.datafiles.Add("234")
    End Sub
End Module
```

Does give me

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

When I use automatic implemented prpoerties

```
Public Class SourceData
    Public Property datafiles() As List(Of String)
End Class
```

---

But it does not when I use a property fully written:

```
Public Class SourceData
    Private _datafiles As New List(Of String)
    Public Property datafiles() As List(Of String)
        Get 
           Return _datafiles
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            _datafiles = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: `As New` is the difference, it ensures the backing variable is not nothing.  You'll need a constructor (Sub New) to do it with an auto-implemented property.

Comment: It's almost always a suspect design to have a settable property of a collection type. Do you really want users of this class to be able to *replace* the existing list with one of their own choosing?

Comment: Duplicate of [List Property Using Auto-Implemented Getter/Setter Returns 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487891/list-property-using-auto-implemented-getter-setter-returns-object-reference-not), in C#, but it doesn't matter in this case and explains the reason. Also [this link about NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) here at SO will be of help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`New`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/new-operator) Operator is missing here:

```
Public Class SourceData
    Public Property datafiles() As List(Of String)
End Class
```